# Help identifying "unknown USB device" in powertop

Tags: usb, 19.10, powertop, unknown-device

I was looking at powertop yesterday when I noticed the following entry in the `tunables` tab:

```
Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-4 (8087:0029)
```

I would like to identify what this "unknown" device is.

`lsusb` gives the following output:

```
sudo lsusb -t -v
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
        ID 27c6:5395  
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
        ID 27c6:5395  
    |__ Port 12: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0c45:6723 Microdia 
    |__ Port 12: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0c45:6723 Microdia
```

If I've understood the `lsusb` output of lsusb correctly then this device seems to be an Intel Wireless adaptor? This confuses me as I'm 99% certain my laptop's wireless card is a Killer AX1650. Is it possible my laptop has 2 wireless adapters?

I checked the [linux-usb USB ids reference](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) and can't find any entry for 0029 under the Intel section (8087).

This is on a Dell XPS15 7590 and I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on it.

Grateful for any pointers as to what this might be or how to determine it.

Edd

Answer (score 0):

8087:0029 is the Bluetooth adapter:

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp.
```

It's a wireless controller, but not WiFi. If you google the ID, you get indications that it is a bluetooth adapter, and the fact that the `btusb` driver is used underpins this.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I had overlooked the fact that bluetooth is of course a type of wireless communication! :-)

I'm curious though, my bluetooth seems to be working just fine, do you know what would cause powertop to consider it an "unknown" device? Is it simply something in the driver which, although it allows the device to work, doesn't provide a name for it?